# Find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues for this linear operator $A:M_{n\times n }\mapsto M_{n\times n}$ defined with $A(X)=X^{T}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues for this linear operator  $A:M_{n\times n }\mapsto M_{n\times n}$ defined with $A(X)=X^{T}$

How does the matrix of this linear operator look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X\neq 0$ be an eigenvector associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda$, so:

$$
A(X)=\lambda X={X}^{T}
$$

So applying the transpose we get:

$$
\lambda X^T=X=\lambda(\lambda X)
$$

Thus:

$$
X({\lambda}^{2}-1)=0
$$

And since $X\neq 0$, then:

$$
{\lambda}^{2}=1
$$

So $\lambda\in\{-1,1\}$

Hence if $X$ is an eigenvector, then $X=X^T$ or $X=-X^T$

Thus the eigenvectors are the vect of antisymmetric matrices and the vect of symmetric matrices.

Answer (score 2):

$\textbf{(BIG) HINT:}$ $A^2 = I$.

Comment: it's identity right?

Comment: Yes, it's right, but doesn't deserve capitals...

Comment: @oussama Thanks for catching the typo :)

Answer (score 1):

If $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, let $E_{ij}$ be the matrix such that the entry at the $i$-th column and $j$-th row is equal to $1$ and all other entries are equal to $0$. Consider the basis of $M_{n\times n}$ whose elements are the matrices $E_{i,i}$ as well as the matrices $E_{i,j}+E_{j,i}$ and $E_{ij}-E_{j,i}$ ($j\neq i$). Each vector of this basis is an eigenvector of $A$.